# Find a value in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm trying to find the row where a value is stock in a QTableView.

I had use 
`QString select = ui->tableView->model()->index(row,0).data().toString();` to collect the value. 
Now i want the exact opposite, like an `indexOf()` but i can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Did you try `QAbstractItemModel::match()` function?

Comment: Finally i make this
`int row=-1;
        for (int var = 0; var < ui->tableView->model()->rowCount(); ++var) {
            if(ui->tableView->model()->index(row,0).data().toString()==file){
               row=var; 
            }
        }`
Thanks @vahancho

Comment: @Nakila_br Please create an answer, when you found the answer yourself. It may be useful for people with the same problem and is much clearer than just a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i make this

```
foreach(QString file, listFile) {
    int row=-1;
    for (int var = 0; var < ui->tableView->model()->rowCount(); ++var) {
        if(ui->tableView->model()->index(row,0).data().toString()==file){
           row=var;
        }
    }
```